# Ext.container.Container / ExtJS: How to jump to the element by id?

Tags: extjs

I am using a page which is extended Ext.container.Container. How to jump to element by id with ExtJS script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to give you an answer that fits your needs. But maybe you can make an example or be a bit more specific in your question.

You can use the `ComponentQuery` to navigate to specific components in your ExtJS application. (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.ComponentQuery.html)

There is also an `up` (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.Container.html#method-up) and `down` (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.Container.html#method-down) selector method which can be used to find components by id like this:

```
let myComponent = myContainer.down('#myComponentID');
```

or

```
let myContainer = containerChild.up('container');
```

You should definitly check out the ComponentQuery documentation to learn more about selector other than id.

And last but not least: Don't use the `@cfg id` to set an id to your component. Use the `@cfg itemId` (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.Widget.html#cfg-itemId).

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways, 
for example:

```
  {
     reference: 'cntainer',
     xtype: 'container',
     itemId: 'cntainer',
     id: 'cntainer'
}
```

you can call it using below methods

```
Ext.getCmp('cntainer')
```

ExtJs has provided different ways to access the element

```
this.lookup('cntainer');
this.lookupReference('cntainer');
this.down('#cntainer');
this.up('#cntainer');
```